# VB.NET delete duplicates in a paritcular range

Tags: vb.net, excel

My app below checks a workbook which has a list of items sold for a particular month identified with a serial number. There is also a comment column next to the item.

Each month when I run the app it tells me if the same item was sold and the comments next to the item.

"Item found in sheet labeled august 2014"
 "Comments for that item"

if I run the app again on the workbook when it gets an additional sheet added, it's going to add the "items found..." Again.

I have the results starting from column 20 and beyond, I only need to delete the duplicates in those columns.

```
Option Explicit On
Option Infer Off
Imports System.Net.Mail
Imports System.IO
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions



Public Class Form1
Dim fileName As String = ""

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load



End Sub
Private Function ColumnIndexToColumnLetter(colIndex As Integer) As String
    Dim div As Integer = colIndex
    Dim colLetter As String = String.Empty
    Dim modnum As Integer = 0
    While div > 0
        modnum = (div - 1) Mod 26
        colLetter = Chr(65 + modnum) & colLetter
        div = CInt((div - modnum) \ 26)
    End While
    Return colLetter
End Function
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Button1.Enabled = False
    Button1.Text = "Patience"
    Button1.Refresh()
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()

    Dim app As New Excel.Application
    app.Visible = False



    Dim wbBase As Excel.Workbook = app.Workbooks.Open(TextBox1.Text)


    '   * create style *
    '
    Dim xlStyles As Excel.Styles = wbBase.Styles
    Dim xlStyle As Excel.Style = Nothing
    Dim isstyleexists As Boolean = False
    '
    '   * check if this style exist *
    '
    For Each xlStyle In xlStyles
        If xlStyle.Name = "NewStyle" Then
            isstyleexists = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    '
    '   * if this does not exist so add new one *
    '               ' get Range "A1"

    If (Not isstyleexists) Then
        xlStyles.Add("NewStyle")
        xlStyle = xlStyles.Item("NewStyle")

    End If







    Dim snName As String
    Dim snName2 As String
    Dim cmt2 As String

    For Each basesheet As Excel.Worksheet In wbBase.Sheets
        Dim iiii As Integer = basesheet.Cells(1, basesheet.Columns.Count).End(Excel.XlDirection.xlToLeft).Column + 1
        Dim iii As Integer = basesheet.Cells(1, basesheet.Columns.Count).End(Excel.XlDirection.xlToLeft).Column + 1
        Dim iv As Integer = iii + 1
        For i As Integer = 1 To 20
            If Not basesheet.Cells(1, i).Value Is Nothing AndAlso basesheet.Cells(1, i).Value.Contains("Serial Number") Then
                snName = ColumnIndexToColumnLetter(i)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If Not snName Is Nothing Then
            For Each checksheet As Excel.Worksheet In wbBase.Sheets
                If basesheet.Name <> checksheet.Name Then

                    For i As Integer = 1 To 20
                        If Not checksheet.Cells(1, i).Value Is Nothing AndAlso checksheet.Cells(1, i).Value.Contains("Serial Number") Then
                            snName2 = ColumnIndexToColumnLetter(i)
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next
                    For i As Integer = 1 To 20
                        If Not checksheet.Cells(1, i).Value Is Nothing AndAlso checksheet.Cells(1, i).Value.Contains("Comments") Then
                            cmt2 = ColumnIndexToColumnLetter(i)
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next
                    If Not snName2 Is Nothing Then

                        Dim baseobj As Object = basesheet.Range(snName & "2:" & snName & basesheet.Range(snName & basesheet.Rows.Count).End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row).Value

                        Dim checkobj As Object = checksheet.Range(snName2 & "2:" & snName2 & checksheet.Range(snName2 & checksheet.Rows.Count).End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row).Value

                        Dim cmtobj As Object = checksheet.Range(cmt2 & "2:" & cmt2 & checksheet.Range(snName2 & checksheet.Rows.Count).End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row).Value

                        Dim basetmp(DirectCast(baseobj, Object(,)).Length, 1) As Object
                        Dim v As Integer = 0
                        Dim bool As Boolean = False
                        For i As Integer = 1 To DirectCast(baseobj, Object(,)).Length

                            For ii As Integer = 1 To DirectCast(checkobj, Object(,)).Length
                                If Not baseobj(i, 1) Is Nothing AndAlso Not checkobj(ii, 1) Is Nothing AndAlso Trim(baseobj(i, 1).ToString) = Trim(checkobj(ii, 1).ToString) Then
                                    bool = True

                                    basetmp(i, 0) = "Serial # Exists in " & checksheet.Name
                                    basetmp(i, 1) = cmtobj(ii, 1)





                                End If

                            Next
                            v += 1
                        Next
                        If bool Then

                            basesheet.Range(basesheet.Cells(1, iii), basesheet.Cells(v, iv)).Style = "NewStyle"
                            basesheet.Range(basesheet.Cells(1, iii), basesheet.Cells(v, iv)).Borders.Weight = Excel.XlBorderWeight.xlThin
                            basesheet.Range(basesheet.Cells(1, iii), basesheet.Cells(v, iv)).Borders.LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous
                            basesheet.Range(basesheet.Cells(1, iii), basesheet.Cells(v, iv)).Value = basetmp
                            basesheet.Cells(1, iii).value = "Results Found"
                            basesheet.Cells(1, iii).Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Red)
                            basesheet.Cells(1, iii).HorizontalAlignment = Excel.Constants.xlCenter
                            basesheet.Cells(1, iii).Font.Bold = True

                            basesheet.Columns.AutoFit()




                            iii += 2
                            iv += 2
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next



    wbBase.Save()
    wbBase.Close()
    app.Quit()
    MessageBox.Show("Done", "Three in Thirty", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
    Button1.Text = "Start"
    Button1.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are reprocessing the previously processed sheets each month.
It might be easier to avoid reprocessing old sheets, than to avoid duplicating entries from reprocessing old sheets.

Instead of using nested loops of worksheets, I would probably try a pattern like:

```
* find basesheet
* find latest checksheet
* process the checksheet for items sold
```

If users might accidentally add things to old sheets, then I would consider locking old sheets when you do the processing to help ensure data integrity.